# iOS app crashed due to [UIFeedbackGenerator _autoDeactivate]

Tags: ios, uifeedbackgenerator

I received the following report from Crashlytics. I was not calling`[UIFeedbackGenerator _autoDeactivate]` myself. Maybe some library was doing that. I have done some research but could not find any useful information. Does anyone know what this crash report means? Thank you!

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>
> Exception raised while auto-deactivating <UISelectionFeedbackGenerator: 0x1c012d7a0: prepared=0> for style 2: force deactivating <UISelectionFeedbackGenerator: 0x1c012d7a0: prepared=0> with style TurnOn which is not active (activationCount = -1) configuration: <_UISelectionFeedbackGeneratorConfiguration: 0x1c0301710: isEnabled=1, activationStyle=2, requiredSupportLevel=0> activationCount: -1, styleActivationCount: -1 engines: {( <_UIFeedbackHapticEngine: 0x1c40dd180: state=4, numberOfClients=5, prewarmCount=0, _isSuspended=0> )}

Here is the full report:

```
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by Sen Liu at Tue, 10 

Oct 2017 22:21:10 GMT
# URL: https://fabric.io/my-app/ios/apps/MyApp.MyApp/issues/59dd3fa2be077a4dcc13b10e?time=last-seven-days/sessions/a519bdec262e49e0be602410c090e407_6e21562fae0411e7918c56847afe9799_0_v2
# Organization: My Company
# Platform: ios
# Application: MyApp
# Version: 0.9 (28)
# Bundle Identifier: MyApp.MyApp
# Issue #: 7
# Issue ID: 59dd3fa2be077a4dcc13b10e
# Session ID: a519bdec262e49e0be602410c090e407_6e21562fae0411e7918c56847afe9799_0_v2
# Date: 2017-10-10T21:46:00Z
# OS Version: 11.0.1 (15A402)
# Device: iPhone 7 Plus
# RAM Free: 5.8%
# Disk Free: 2.5%

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  MyApp                    0x100ab1ec4 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1572
1  MyApp                    0x100ab1ec4 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1572
2  MyApp                    0x100ab1d80 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1248
3  MyApp                    0x100aa1670 CLSHandler + 48
4  MyApp                    0x100aafcc0 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 92
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ab5048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x182abdae8 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  MyApp                    0x100aaf764 CLSExceptionRecord + 212
8  MyApp                    0x100aaf598 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 548
9  MyApp                    0x100aaf1b8 CLSTerminateHandler() + 396
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x18263454c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x1826345b8 std::terminate() + 60
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18264476c _destroyAltHandlerList + 10
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ab505c _dispatch_client_callout + 36
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x182abd3d4 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 428
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ac6ca4 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 1588
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ac1a4c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 720
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1830d7f20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1830d5afc __CFRunLoopRun + 2012
19 CoreFoundation                 0x182ff62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
20 GraphicsServices               0x184e87f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
21 UIKit                          0x18c5a3880 UIApplicationMain + 208
22 MyApp                    0x10099a4cc main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x182b1a56c start + 4

--

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18312fd38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182644528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18312fc80 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  UIKit                          0x18cf6b6d8 -[UIFeedbackGenerator _autoDeactivate]
4  UIKit                          0x18cf6b408 __48-[UIFeedbackGenerator _setupAutoDeactivateTimer]_block_invoke
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ab5048 _dispatch_client_callout
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x182abd3d4 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ac6ca4 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ac1a4c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d7f20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1830d5afc __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x182ff62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 GraphicsServices               0x184e87f84 GSEventRunModal
13 UIKit                          0x18c5a3880 UIApplicationMain
14 MyApp                    0x10099a4cc main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x182b1a56c start

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  MyApp                    0x100ab1ec4 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1572
1  MyApp                    0x100ab1ec4 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1572
2  MyApp                    0x100ab1d80 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1248
3  MyApp                    0x100aa1670 CLSHandler + 48
4  MyApp                    0x100aafcc0 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 92
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x182ab5048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x182abdae8 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  MyApp                    0x100aaf764 CLSExceptionRecord + 212
8  MyApp                    0x100aaf598 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 548
9  MyApp                    0x100aaf1b8 CLSTerminateHandler() + 396
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x18263454c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x1826345b8 std::terminate() + 60
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18264476c _destroyAltHandlerList + 10
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ab505c _dispatch_client_callout + 36
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x182abd3d4 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 428
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ac6ca4 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 1588
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x182ac1a4c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 720
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1830d7f20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1830d5afc __CFRunLoopRun + 2012
19 CoreFoundation                 0x182ff62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
20 GraphicsServices               0x184e87f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
21 UIKit                          0x18c5a3880 UIApplicationMain + 208
22 MyApp                    0x10099a4cc main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x182b1a56c start + 4

#1. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac2c start_wqthread + 122

#2. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28a3c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d7ce4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d58b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4  CoreFoundation                 0x182ff62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  Foundation                     0x183a1e6e4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x183a3dafc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7  UIKit                          0x18d0ef02c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x183b1f860 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c32c _pthread_body + 308
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c1f8 _pthread_body + 310
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac38 thread_start + 4

#3. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28a3c mach_msg + 72
2  MyApp                    0x100a9c17c CLSMachExceptionServer + 100
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c32c _pthread_body + 308
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c1f8 _pthread_body + 310
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac38 thread_start + 4

#4. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c49dbc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5afb0 _pthread_wqthread + 884
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac30 start_wqthread + 4

#5. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c49dbc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5afb0 _pthread_wqthread + 884
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac30 start_wqthread + 4

#6. com.apple.CFStream.LegacyThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28a3c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d7ce4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d58b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4  CoreFoundation                 0x182ff62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1830e6f28 _legacyStreamRunLoop_workThread + 272
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c32c _pthread_body + 308
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c1f8 _pthread_body + 310
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac38 thread_start + 4

#7. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28a3c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d7ce4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d58b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4  CoreFoundation                 0x182ff62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  CFNetwork                      0x18375fb40 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404
6  Foundation                     0x183b1f860 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c32c _pthread_body + 308
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c1f8 _pthread_body + 310
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac38 thread_start + 4

#8. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c49570 __select + 8
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1830e021c __CFSocketManager + 644
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c32c _pthread_body + 308
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c1f8 _pthread_body + 310
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac38 thread_start + 4

#9. AVAudioSession Notify Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c28a3c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d7ce4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1830d58b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4  CoreFoundation                 0x182ff62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5  AVFAudio                       0x1888bf774 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6  AVFAudio                       0x1888ea018 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c32c _pthread_body + 308
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5c1f8 _pthread_body + 310
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac38 thread_start + 4

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182c49dbc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5b144 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182d5ac30 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Do you have any third party libraries in your project? If so, check if any dependency uses the UIFeedbackGenerator.

Comment: I'm seeing the same log. Have you found out what caused it?

Comment: I restarted xcode and it was fixed. Can be apple's bug. @Bonan

Comment: My crashlog is from live version, so restarting Xcode is not likely to fix it I suppose...Thanks anyway. @ukim

Comment: I got the same and have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: It seems that issue is from any of the third-party libraries you used. Those library may use UIFeedbackGenerator and which leads crashes. Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, you can check the following steps:

1. `cd` to your project's root path
2. Run

   ```
   grep -r UIFeedbackGenerator .
   ```

Then you will find which library is using `UIFeedbackGenerator`.

Hope this will help you.