# UIFeedbackGenerator _autoDeactivate crashes iOS 11.2.2

Tags: ios, ios11, haptic-feedback

I am seeing intermittent crashes with the haptic feedback engine in iOS 11. Unfortunately, I do not have reproducible steps because it seems to be happening randomly.

Here are the exception and stack traces:

> Exception raised while auto-deactivating <UIImpactFeedbackGenerator: 0x1c850a710: prepared=0> for style 2: force deactivating <UIImpactFeedbackGenerator: 0x1c850a710: prepared=0> with style TurnOn which is not active (activationCount = -1) configuration: <_UIImpactFeedbackGeneratorConfiguration: 0x1c80bc920: isEnabled=1, activationStyle=2, requiredSupportLevel=2> activationCount: -1, styleActivationCount: -1 engines: {( <_UIFeedbackHapticOnlyEngine: 0x1c80db040: state=4, numberOfClients=1, prewarmCount=0, _isSuspended=0> )}

```
# Platform: ios
# Application: MyApp
# Version: 3.1.0.4
# Bundle Identifier: com.company.myApp
# Issue #: 8845
# Issue ID: 59ff154761b02d480dd20c28
# Session ID: 2ec9b043edaa4fcaad12fa480d690e8a_0c4f8c61fbbd11e7924356847afe9799_0_v2
# Date: 2018-01-17T19:31:00Z
# OS Version: 11.2.2 (15C202)
# Device: iPhone 8
# RAM Free: 20.8%
# Disk Free: 82.9%

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  MyApp                  0x100d02fb8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1125008
1  MyApp                  0x100d02fb8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1125008
2  MyApp                  0x100d02e74 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1124684
3  MyApp                  0x100cf2fa0 CLSHandler + 1059448
4  MyApp                  0x100d00fd0 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 1116840
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1853aaa14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1853e7d4c _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  MyApp                  0x100d00a64 CLSExceptionRecord + 1115452
8  MyApp                  0x100d0088c CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 1114980
9  MyApp                  0x100d004a0 CLSTerminateHandler() + 1113976
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x184c6454c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x184c645b8 std::terminate() + 60
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x184c7476c _destroyAltHandlerList + 10
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1853aaa28 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1853e7640 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 420
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1853f0858 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 528
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1853ebb64 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 684
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1859d6544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1859d4120 __CFRunLoopRun + 2012
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1858f3e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
20 GraphicsServices               0x1877a0f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
21 UIKit                          0x18f04867c UIApplicationMain + 236
22 MyApp                        0x10049e760 main (main.mm:34)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x18541056c start + 4

--

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x185a2e364 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x184c74528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x185a2e2ac -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  UIKit                          0x18fa29198 -[UIFeedbackGenerator _autoDeactivate]
4  UIKit                          0x18fa28ec8 __48-[UIFeedbackGenerator _setupAutoDeactivateTimer]_block_invoke
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1853aaa14 _dispatch_client_callout
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1853e7640 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1853f0858 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$armv81
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1853ebb64 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1859d6544 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1859d4120 __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1858f3e58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 GraphicsServices               0x1877a0f84 GSEventRunModal
13 UIKit                          0x18f04867c UIApplicationMain
14 MyApp                      0x10049e760 main (main.mm:34)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x18541056c start
```

Have others run into this issue?

Comment: Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676999/ios-app-crashed-due-to-uifeedbackgenerator-autodeactivate